# How to encrypt and signed an email in c# with attachment

Tags: c#, email, encryption, sign

i'm trying to send an email with attachment and need to encrypt it AND sign it.
I can encrypt it, I can sign it but when i try to do both i get an email signed with unreadable text or an e-mail encrypte with clear text no PJ only the base64string.

thanks for your answer.
this is my code for better answer :

```
string message = BuildMessage(body, pjs, false);
byte[] messageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(messageData));
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, GetCertificateFromEmailFrom(from));
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);

byte[] signedBytes = signedCms.Encode();
ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(signedBytes);
EnvelopedCms envelopeCms = new EnvelopedCms(content);
CmsRecipientCollection toRecipientCollection = new CmsRecipientCollection();
Dictionary<string, X509Certificate2> certificatesForEncryption = new Dictionary<string, X509Certificate2>();
List<string> mailRefuser = GetCertificateFromEMailTo(to, out certificatesForEncryption);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, X509Certificate2> certificate in certificatesForEncryption)
{
    CmsRecipient recipient = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, certificate.Value);
    toRecipientCollection.Add(recipient);
}
envelopeCms.Encrypt(toRecipientCollection);
byte[] encryptedBytes = envelopeCms.Encode();

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress(from);
foreach (string toMail in to)
{
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toMail));
}
msg.Subject = subject;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes);
AlternateView av = new AlternateView(ms, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data"); //"application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;name=smime.p7m; content-transfer-encoding=utf-8; content-disposition=attachment; fileName=smime.p7m;");
msg.AlternateViews.Add(av);


SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerSMTPWithCredentials"]);
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certifficate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem like a minimal, complete example.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MimeKit (as it looks like it).Create the signed MultiPart Message, encrypt it and put it as the message body.

```
var ctx = new MimeKit.Cryptography.WindowsSecureMimeContext();
var signed = MultipartSigned.Create (ctx, signer, mimeMessage.Body);
var encrypted = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.Encrypt (ctx, toRecipientCollection, signed);
mimeMessage.Body = encrypted;
```